# CMake Error: TARGET_PDB_FILE is not supported by the target linker

Tags: opencv, cmake, g++

I am working on an older i386 laptop, and since no i386 builds of CMake are provided at https://cmake.org/download/ I have built my own i386 build of CMake 3.19.4.  I am now using that to build an old OpenCV 2.3.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 using g++ 7.5.0.  When I try that, I get lots of lines like the following one:

```
CMake Error:
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PDB_FILE:opencv_stitching>

  TARGET_PDB_FILE is not supported by the target linker.
```

After some investigation, I found that this is caused by the following line that appears in several CMakeLists.txt files scattered across OpenCV source directory:

```
install(FILES $<TARGET_PDB_FILE:${the_target}> DESTINATION bin COMPONENT main)
```

If I comment out these lines, then that seems to solve the problem.  However, I prefer not to do that because this line *is* actually useful for my Windows OpenCV build.  I prefer to have the PDB files installed for debugging purposes.

So what exactly is the reason for this error and how can I solve it in a clean way so that the build passes on Linux, and I still have my PDB files on Windows?

Answer (score 3):

If an command is only suited for a special platform or compiler you can include that in an if clause, e.g. in your case

```
if (MSVC)
  install(FILES $<TARGET_PDB_FILE:${the_target}> DESTINATION bin COMPONENT main)
endif()
```